# Want to compress a folder in application/x-zip-compressed format

Tags: file, compression, format, directory

I have a folder inside that folder I have css file and images.. I want to compress that folder in application/x-zip-compressed format. But I am unable to compress it..

What I have tried I compress it in Zip and try to convert the format online..
I checked in google but unable to find a solutions..

I want to upload a folder in this format in my project..

Please help me out !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's so special about "x-zip"? Is it even a "real format" (meaning not something home made), I can't find it on [IANA's list of "application/*" MIME types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application).

I had no problems uploading my zip files as static resources made with Winzip, 7Zip, WinRAR, Windows's native "compressed folder" thingie, Linux's gzip...

Is your problem specific to OSX or something? Can't you just install one of many free programs capable of making *.zip archives or use Windows "right click the directory -> Send to -> compressed (zipped) folder"?

Quick Google search brings up stuff like http://createzipfiles.com/ but that means you're OK uploading your content to $_GOD knows what kind of website...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which was simply: "How do I create an application/x-zip-compressed format file?"

Comment: @Gerald The question was edited after I've answerred, Salesforce.com related bit and tags were removed... Technically you're correct with your downwote now but the original intent of the question was "how can I create a zip file I can upload to Salesforce". Old SF docs mentioned x-zip for some weird reason, now it's cleaner: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_resources.htm